# How to pass an array of functions as argument to another function and invoke these function in the later function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Recently I use `async` to control the workflow. I want to execute a set of functions asynchronously. Using node module `async`.
Below is my code

```
var async = require('async')
var resArray = [],
    exeFunction = []
var addOne = function (num) {
    resArray.push(10)
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    exeFunction.push(addOne(num))
}

async.waterfall(exeFunction,function () {
    console.log(resArray)
})
```

It doesn't work.(Forgive my stupidity)
when I change the code like this:

```
var async = require('async')
var resArray = []
var exeFunction = []
var addOne = function () {
    resArray.push(10)
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    exeFunction.push(addOne)
}

async.waterfall(exeFunction,function () {
    console.log(resArray)
})
```

it still doesn't work. 
It is wrong? How to fix it?

I'm new to `nodejs`, any kind of advice will be very good. thanks!

PS: The regular for iterator works well in this condition.but I want to know how to use `async` in this way.

Comment: The way with which you are making use of `asyn.waterfall` is wrong. please refer documentation https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `callback` function in order to go [to the next task](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall), like this

```
var async       = require('async');
var exeFunction = [];
var resArray    = [];

var addOne = function (num) {
    return function (next) {
      resArray.push(10); // or resArray.push(num)
      next(null);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  exeFunction.push(addOne(i));
}

async.waterfall(exeFunction, function (err, res) {
    console.log(resArray)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var c1=function(){  // Create First Element of array of functions
  alert("In C1");
}
var c2=function(){ // Create Second Element of array of functions
  alert("In C2");
}
var childs=[c1,c2]; // Create array of functions
function parentfunc(funcs){ // Create a function which will invoke array of functions
  alert("In Parent");
  for(var i=0;i<funcs.length;i++){ 
    if(typeof(funcs[i])=="function"){ // Invoke a function from array of functions
      funcs[i]();
    }
  }
}
parentfunc(childs); // Invoke function which will invoke array of functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna do that:

```
var async = require('async')

var resArray = [],
    exeFunction = [
        function(callback) {
            callback(null, 0)
        }
    ]
;
var addOne = function(num, callback) {
    resArray.push(num)
    callback(++num)
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    exeFunction.push(addOne)
}

async.waterfall(exeFunction, function() {
    console.log(resArray)
})
```

Your error is that you give the return of the function `addDone` (here `undefined`) when you want to give the function itself.